# Use java.io.File in PeopleCode to list files in directory

Tags: peoplesoft-app-engine

I would like to be able to create a list ,array, of file names on a folder so that I can use PeopleCode to loop through them and delete files that match a pattern and are in a date range.

I'm pretty sure I have the last half of that, matching a pattern and in a date range, but I do not know how to get the list on remote servers.  I can do it on our local servers, but not remote ones.

I had hoped that this would work:
Local object &files = CreateJavaObject("java.io.File", SFO_DEL_FTP_AET.FTPDIRECTORY | "*.*");
But I don't think it is working.

Can somebody help me?

Thanks,

JPS

Comment: I sort of have this working but filtering things out is a nightmare.

Does anybody know how to set a filter?

It looks like this should work, but it fails:

Local JavaObject &joFilter = CreateJavaObject("java.io.FilenameFilter");

 &joFilter.setfilenamefilter = SFO_DEL_FTP_AET.FILENAME;

Answer (score 1):

You can use Java to access/modify the files in a directory. Try:

```
Local JavaObject instead of Local object
```

We created a PS component to view, upload, and delete files in an App Server directory. You can see how we did it here:

https://github.com/cy2hq/PeopleSoft-Directory-Viewer

Comment: Thanks, but I am trying to do this on remote servers.  I already can do it using PeopleCode to get the list of files and the java to delete.

What I need to be able to do is to list them on remote servers, not ours.

Comment: Missed the remote, part. If it is a mounted/mapped network directory/drive, sure it will work. FTP, no.